# On the concept of "similarity"

Tags: definition, math-history

According to "The Words of Mathematics" by Steven Schwartzman, similarity in mathematics means "*two similar things [that] look as if they're "one and the same" in respect to a certain property*".

Examples thereof that come to my mind are:

- similar matrices, representing the same linear map up to change of base;
- similar triangles (or geometric shapes more generally), whose angles are the same, but the absolute size may differ.

According to the definition of Schwartzman one could apply the notion "similarity / similar" to a variety of concepts in mathematics that are given other names, e.g.:

- homeomorphic topological spaces;
- equivalence classes (e.g., in $\mathbb{Q}$);
- isomorphic groups/rings/fiels;
- equivalence of categories.

I am wondering how the term "similarity" and the mathematical concept of it emerged historically (e.g., Leibnitz introduced the symbol $\sim$ as far as I know, but what where the first concepts of similarity in mathematics?). And could one find a general (precise mathematical) definition of equivalence, that subsumes every of those mentioned cases?

More examples of similarities in mathematics are also appreciated.

In addition to the question of capturing similarity purely within mathematics, I would be interested to know what possibilities there are to classify/examine things/objects from everyday life mathematically for similarity.

Comment: Despite of some rigorous definitions in mathematics about similarity , usually "similar" is a somewhat opinion-based property. For example , whether two particular humans look similar is probably judged differently by different people. It depends on the properties one demands for similarity how formal and precise the definition can be made.

Answer (score -1):

Historically similarity is a "weak" form of the logic of identity.

Leibnitz's principle of the "equality of the indiscernibles" states that $x=y$ if every property of $x$ is also of $y$

$x=y\iff (F)(Fx\iff Fy)$

where $F$ is any predicate (property).

From this we can derive the reflexivity,  symmetry and transitivity of the identity.

Now, similarity is a weak form since the condition of "all properties" is weakened to "some property".

Yet similarity is an equivalence relation.
It is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

In linear algebra for example two square matrices are similar if they have the property:
$A\sim B\iff(\exists T)(det(T)\neq 0 \land B=T^{-1}AT)$

however they are not equal since they satisfy only a certain property.

The same is true for isomorphism of vector spaces and homomorphism of topological spaces

Comment: Whether "similar" is an equivalence relation depends on what we consider to be "similar". An example where we do not have an equivalence relation , but in daily life we would use "similar". Say , the lengths of streets are considered to be similar, if the difference is at most $5m$. Then, for streets with lengths $95m$ , $100m$ and $105m$ , we do not have the transitivity property.

Comment: Well if we extend the notion of similarity from geometry of similar triangles it remains an equivalence relation. I think what you are referring to is the notion of "like" which is not transitive. Read Patrick Suppes, "Introduction to logic", your analogy of streets is referred there as a 'like' relation.

Comment: A similar analogy to yours is in perception of colors 'red alike'